# How can I get identifier style to apply to '%' (in a Perl listing)?

Tags: listings, perl

When using Perl variable names with sigils with `listings`, the `$` and `@` sigils somehow get coloured in `identifierstyle`, but the `%` sigil remains unstyled.

Therefore, this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{perl}{
   language=Perl,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
   commentstyle=\color{purple!40!black},
   identifierstyle=\color{blue},
   stringstyle=\color{orange},
}

\lstset{style=perl}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        my ($a, $b, $c) = ('a'..'z');
        my ($a, $b, @c) = ('a'..'z');
        my ($a, $b, %c) = ('a'..'z');
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

gives this result:

[image: unstyled sigil]

Is there a way I could make `listings` understand that `%` should have the same style as `$` or `@`?

The manual is pretty clear about keywords and comments, but it didn't help me understand the difference between an identifier and an operator (?) that doesn't get styled. Looking at the Perl language definition in `lstlang1.sty` didn't help either since there is nothing there about either `$` and `@` or `%`.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs: thank you, I have done as you suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer

By default, identifiers cannot start by `%`. You can allow identifiers to start by `%` by specifying `alsoletter={\%}` in the definition of your custom `perl` style.

### Detailed answer

Look up the `alsoletter` key in subsection 4.18 of the `listings` manual:

> All identifiers (keywords, directives, and such) consist of a letter followed by alpha-numeric characters (letters and digits). For example, if you write `keywords={one-two,\#include}`, the minus sign must become a digit and the sharp a letter since the keywords can’t be detected otherwise.

According to Table 2, `%` is (by default) treated, not as a "letter", but as "other". The `Perl` style (which is defined in `lstdrvrs.dtx`, a file that ships with `listings.sty`) doesn't change that.

Therefore, in order to allow identifiers to begin by `%`, you must specify `alsoletter={\%}`. Note that `%` must be escaped, here; see item 5 in subsection 4.1 for more details.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{perl}
{
   language=Perl,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
   commentstyle=\color{purple!40!black},
   identifierstyle=\color{blue},
   stringstyle=\color{orange},
   alsoletter={\%},
}

\lstset{style=perl}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        my ($a, $b, $c) = ('a'..'z');
        my ($a, $b, @c) = ('a'..'z');
        my ($a, $b, %c) = ('a'..'z');
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that e.g.  `$a % 15` now gets the `%` rendered as an identifier, when it is an operator. Oh, the wonders of Perl...