# Why does a space destroy my keywords in listingspackage?

Tags: listings, keywords

I am using the following:

```
\usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{
      language=C,
      keywordstyle=\color{pantone309!90},
      morekeywords={
        omp,
        parallel,
        \#pragma
        }
    }
```

When i now write this

```
\begin{lstlisting}
#pragma
#define
    #pragma
    #define
\end{lstlisting}
```

It looks like this:[image: Output of my example]

How can i fix this, so that it all pragmas are highlighted as keyword ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: AFAIK in Listings the C/C++ preprocessor directives such as `#define` etc. are formatted not with `keywordstyle` but with `directivestyle`.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142582/how-can-i-get-identifier-style-to-apply-to-in-a-perl-listing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define `\#key` in `otherkeywords` (page 44 of the manual)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  keywordstyle=\color{green!70!blue},
  morekeywords={
    omp,
    parallel,
  }
  alsoother={\#},
  otherkeywords={\#pragma,\#define},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
#pragma
#define
    #pragma
    #define
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Sorry for the change in the color; it was easier to define a new one than searching how to use Pantone colors.)

Comment: Thanks, was looking for this ! Color was just an example, your green is just fine :P