# Listings refuses to highlight identifiers such as 'intent–filter'. Why?

Tags: listings, highlighting, xml

I have some xml code, which I want to look fine in my latexdocument.
I am doing it this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}



\lstset{
basicstyle=\fontsize{12}{12},
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
stringstyle =\color[rgb]{0,0,1}\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133}\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\color[RGB]{49,0,171}\ttfamily,
emph= {action,intent–filter,category, receiver, application, activity, manifest},
emphstyle={\color[RGB]{63,127,127}},alsoletter={-},
}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

 \begin{lstlisting} [language=xml] 
<intent-filter>

  </intent-filter>
\end{lstlisting}
```

\end{document}

I am using it for java and xml. It looks fine, but "intent-filter" remains black, the other keywords (I have removed it here) becomes green. Using "intentfilter" works, but it have to be "intent-filter".
How can I do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `listings` doesn't allow for `-` in identifiers by default. You must tell it do so explicitly, using `alsoletter=-`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have edited it. I tried it with also letter, but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get identifier style to apply to '%' (in a Perl listing)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142582/how-can-i-get-identifier-style-to-apply-to-in-a-perl-listing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `listings` doesn't allow for hyphens `-` in identifiers. You must tell it do so explicitly, using `alsoletter=-`. This modification should take place *after* loading the desired language, because the `alsoletter` key is (commonly) used in `listings`' language definitions. Therefore, loading a language too late is likely to overwrite your earlier `alsoletter` specs.

The following *should* work:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=xml,alsoletter=-]
<intent-filter><xyz>blablabla</xyz></intent-filter>
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

*Should* but doesn't. Why? Because, in

```
emph= {action,intent–filter,category, receiver, application, activity, manifest}
```

the `–` character is an en-dash character ([U+2013](http://unicode-table.com/en/2013/)), whereas, in your listing, you use hyphens ([U+002D](http://unicode-table.com/en/002D/)). Those two characters only look similar to you, but `listings` sees them as two distinct characters.

Things get highlighted as expected if you use hyphens throughout.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\fontsize{12}{12},
columns=fullflexible,
showstringspaces=false,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
stringstyle =\color[rgb]{0,0,1}\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133}\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\color[RGB]{49,0,171}\ttfamily,
emph= {action,intent-filter,category, receiver, application, activity, manifest},
emphstyle={\color[RGB]{63,127,127}},alsoletter={-},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=xml,alsoletter=-]
<intent-filter><xyz>blablabla</xyz></intent-filter>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```